# 窶 use in compound words

Tags: definitions

Does 窶 form compounds? Jisho and another dictionary I checked has no compounds listed, and I know they are Japanese and not Chinese. I think it germinates a series of potentially offensive political terms? If so, thank you for introducing these concepts to me because I am totally ignorant of them.

Comment: Can you show us where you've come across this character?  Any examples or context that made you think it can be used to form potentially offensive political terms?  It sounds like you have a specific reason you've chosen to ask this question, but you haven't shared it with us.

Comment: These terms are in computer data sources and are used to markup existing source text. When processed as Chinese text, the kanji (and sometimes other symbols) are processed differently, so I know it’s Japanese. It seems like some sort of politically-motivated vandalism to me.    Thank you for your feedback; I am surprised no one else recognizes this kanji and what I am talking about.

Comment: Here’s a simple example I can share from a reference list. This one isn’t a compound: ——-“Pubrarians and Liblishers at 20: Reflections on Library Publishing from 1995窶2014." Journal of Librarianship and Scholarly Communication 2(4):eP1201. http://dx.doi.org/10.7710/2162-3309.1201——

Comment: When I follow your link, I see U+2013 'en dash'.  I don't see U+7AB6 `窶`.  Is it possible there was some sort of software error causing it to be rendered as the wrong character, perhaps due to differing encodings?

Comment: Sorry, that link was part of the citation. I am taking about a info database that is one “meta” above that data line. In other words, you are right, that link works, but the data I have has a data line that does not have the hyphen, instead it has the kanji.... If this is confusing, I understand. I’m very happy I could run this past some computer-savvy Japanese readers and see that this is not a common problem. Thank you, you have been a big help already.

Comment: It's an encoding error: U+2013 'en dash' in UTF-8 is `e28093`, and  U+7AB6 `窶` encoded in [Shift_JIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/Shift_JIS/index.htm) is `e280`. Which leaves an extraneous `93`, which might result in another messed up character in your database. Shift_JIS is a somewhat common encoding in Japan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to several sources including [this](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/syuusyuu9701/e/69119e906058b6c45ad8a4c10b42a976), it forms several compounds:

- 甌窶（おうろう）
- 貧窶（ひんく／ひんる）
- 窶国（くこく）
- 窶困（くじん）

But these are very rare and only kanji maniacs will need them. This kanji itself means "poverty" or "emaciation", so theoretically it can form some negative derogatory compound, but I know no real example. It may have been used actively in the past or in some country outside Japan.

Comment: The list of kanji strings I have are different and are probably just computer gibberish then, maybe an encoding issue. Thank you for clearing up this reoccurring problem I am having with these unusual random text strings.